# Copy files from multiple locations defined in ItemGroup

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

Project file:

```xml
...
<ItemGroup>
    <MyConfigProject Include="..\Project1.Config"></MyConfigProject>
    <MyConfigProject Include="..\Project2.Config"></MyConfigProject>
    ....
    <MyConfigProject Include="..\ProjectN.Config"></MyConfigProject>
</ItemGroup>
...
```

I need to copy all *.resx files from config projects subfolders Resources to single folder.
e.g.

```
copy ..\Project1.Config\Resources\*.resx to C:\myproject.
```

I found a lot of examples that use batching for copying group of files to multiple folders, but couldn't find example of copying files from multiple folders to single location.

NOTE: I don't want to specify Resources folder in every MyConfigProject item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just:

```
  <Target Name="Itemgroup">
  <ItemGroup>
      <MyProjects Include="Project1;
                           Project2;Project3"></MyProjects>
  </ItemGroup>


  <Message Text="..\%(MyProjects.Identity).Config\Resources\*.resx"/>

  <ItemGroup>
      <MyConfigProject Include="..\%(MyProjects.Identity).Config\Resources\*.resx"/>
  </ItemGroup>


<Copy SourceFiles="@(MyConfigProject)" DestinationFolder="C:\SomeNewFolder"/>
  </Target>
```

Comment: I need to have complete control over project list whose resources are included. Depending on web project configuration I need to copy one or many config project resources. So, I can't include all config projects resources into copy.

Comment: Then create an itemgroup -files based on an itemgroup of projects.

Comment: I already solved this by appending /resources/*.resx to include of every MyConfigProject item (which I didn't want to do as stated in NOTE of my question). Is there a solution that would work without repeating /Resources/*.resx in every item?

Comment: I had a problem with my solution, so I switched to your suggestions. It works perfectly.